# php curl and CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION behavior

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, content-type

Here's the situation. On one side, we have a server, with a RESTful service. One possible query to it is a POST query to create an object. When that is done, the server returns a 'Location' header, to indicate where information on the newly created object can be found.
However, said server is anal about having the correct Content-Type for each request. For instance, POST requires 'application/json', and GET requires this to be unset (make sense, since GET doesn't have a body).

**To sum up, we have:**

- *www.example.com/articles/* ; one can send a **POST** request with `'Content-Type: application/json'`, and server will return `'Location: www.example.com/articles/123'` if `123` is the `id` of the new object ;
- *www.example.com/articles/123* ; one can send a **GET** request with no `'Content-Type'` and server will return a description of the new article object.

On client side, we use **PHP** with **cURL**. We use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`setting so we can read the description of the newly created object. Obviously, we also set `'Content-Type: application/json'` for our POST request:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"name": "test"}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com/Articles/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

This is what we get:

```
string(101) "{ "errorNo": 415, "error": "Unsupported Media Type Content-Type should not be set in a GET request" }"
```

I looked at the log of the server, and indeed, `'Content-Type: application/json'` is sent to GET *www.example.com/articles/123*.

**Is this an expected behaviour?**
If yes, what is then best approach:

- remove the `'Content-Type'` check on GET requests, server-side?
  (sounds silly)
- forget about `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, and make 2 clearly separated curl requests, so I have control over the headers? (but then what's the point of `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?)
- something else?

For control and testing, I also use **Postman**, and I have no problem with it, it follows the location, doesn't send the `'Content-Type'` on the GET part (apparently) after the redirection and so I don't have an error.

**EDIT**:
There seems to be nothing useful in the PHP doc. But I found something interesting in the command line man page:

```
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
```

It says:

```
"WARNING: headers set with this option will be set in all requests - even after redirects are followed, like when told with -L, --location."
```

So I guess it probably is the expected behaviour for PHP too. May someone suggest best practices then?

Comment: Aren't postfields supposed to be in the `param1=val1&...` format?

Comment: not necessarily ; this API understands JSON for instance

Comment: There seems to be nothing useful in the PHP doc. But I found something interesting in the command line man page:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

to set the post type

Comment: Yes, this forced the method to stay POST on the redirected request, instead of becoming GET (which is what I wanted), meaning a POST with "Content-Type: application/json" on www.example.com/articles/123. This is the opposite of what I need.